# 'Sequential' object has no attribute '_call_spec'

Tags: python, tensorflow, opencv, computer-vision, object-detection

I did not find a solution to this problem, I searched the Internet and did not find a solution
It was in the beginning

`# classIndex = int(model.predict_classes(img))`

I amended it as it is and did not fix the error

`

```
import numpy as np
import cv2
import pickle

#########################################
width = 640
height = 480
threshold = 0.80
#########################################

cap = cv2.VideoCapture(0)
cap.set(3, width)
cap.set(4, height)

pickle_in = open("model_trained_10.p", "rb")
model = pickle.load(pickle_in)
#pdm_temp = pickle.load(model)

 
def preProcessing(img):
    img = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
    img = cv2.equalizeHist(img)
    img = img/255
    return img


while True:
    success, imgOriginal = cap.read()
    img = np.asarray(imgOriginal)
    img = cv2.resize(img, (32,32))
    img = preProcessing(img)
    cv2.imshow("Processed Image", img)
    img = img.reshape(1,32,32)
    print(model)
    #predict
    classIndex = np.argmax(model.predict(img))


    # classIndex = int(model.predict_classes(img))
    # classIndex=int(model.rstudio(img)) 
    # classes_x=np.argmax(classIndex,axis=1)
    #print(classIndex)
    predictions = model.predict(img)
    probVal = np.amax(predictions)
    print(classIndex,probVal)

    if probVal> cv2.threshold:
        cv2.putText(imgOriginal, str(classIndex) + "  " + str(probVal), (50,50), cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_COMPLEX, 1, (0, 0, 255), 1)
    

    cv2.imshow("Original Image", imgOriginal)

    if cv2.waitKey(1) & 0xFF == ord('q'):
        break
```

`

Comment: Is your model saved from keras/tensorflow libraries ?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Yes I used keras/tensorflow libraries